# MySQL, SELECT with COUNT, but GROUP BY if sort

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like these:

Table "users":

```
user_id | source
----------------
      1 | 2
      2 | 2
      3 | 3
      4 | 0
```

Table "sources":

```
source_id | name
----------------
        1 | "one"
        2 | "two"
        3 | "three"
        4 | "four"
```

Now I need to SELECT (*) FROM `source` and additionally COUNT "users" that have this source, BUT if there is an additional filter(requests by PHP mysqli), then additionally sort "sources" table by its users count.

What is the best way to do so, and is it possible to do in one statement?

--------------Added editing----------

The first part(SELECT with count from another table) I'm doing this way:

```
SELECT 
    id, name
    (select count(*) from users where source = sources.id) as sourceUsersCount
FROM sources
```

And now, how to order this list by users count in each source?

Comment: Which part of your problem you can't solve?

Comment: Like this? `SELECT source_id, name, count(*) as count_of_users FROM sources INNER JOIN users ON sources.source_id = users.source GROUP BY source_id, name ORDER BY count_of_users;` You'll have to share what you mean by "But if there is additional filter(requests by php mysqli)" What's a "filter" in this context. What isn't solved by the above sql statement that you would need to solve for yet?

Comment: `INNER JOIN` doesn't return all rows from `sources` table. Had to use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved it by doing so:

```
SELECT 
    sources.*,
    count(users.source) as sourceUsersCount
FROM sources
LEFT JOIN users ON sources.id = users.source
//In case of additional filters
WHERE 
    id != 0 AND (name LIKE %?% OR id LIKE %?%)
//\\
GROUP BY sources.id 
//In case of sorting by "users" count
ORDER BY sourceUsersCount ASC 
//\\
```

Is it the best way, or maybe there are some faster variants?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below query if this is what you need.

```
select s.*,a.c from sources s
left join
 (select count(*) as c,source as src 
   from user u join sources s 
      on s.source_id = u.source group by u.source) a 
on s.source_id = a.src;
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of users:

```
SELECT sources.*, COUNT(users.user_id) FROM sources
LEFT JOIN users ON users.source_id = sources.source_id
GROUP BY sources.source_id;
```

I assume by filters you mean the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT sources.*, COUNT(users.user_id) FROM sources
LEFT JOIN users ON users.source_id = sources.source_id
WHERE sources.source_id = 2
GROUP BY sources.source_id;
```

And you can always attach an `ORDER BY` on the end for sorting:

```
SELECT sources.*, COUNT(users.user_id) FROM sources
LEFT JOIN users ON users.source_id = sources.source_id
GROUP BY sources.source_id
ORDER BY sources.source_id DESC;
```

Comment: It works good to count `users` with the same `source`. The thing is that statement must always return the full list of `sources` with additional variable of `users` count(like in your example). And sometimes statement must be modified to return `filtered` rows. Like adding there ``WHERE id != 0 AND (users.name LIKE ? OR sources.name LIKE ?)``. And sometimes the statement must be sorted like ``ORDER BY`` by `users` amount in a source. And sometimes `sorted` and `filtered` at the same time.

Comment: @passwd Yep, so if you combine my 2nd and 3rd examples you should get the result you need. Just make sure the `WHERE` appears before the `GROUP BY` and the `ORDER BY` appears after.